# Usando Cycle2 e "picturefill" juntos

Tags: jquery, imagem, cycle2

Criei um *slideshow* responsivo usando o Cycle2. Como as imagens são muito grandes, preciso carregar um arquivo menor de cada imagem quando a página for aberta em dispositivos móveis.

Por isso, pensei em utilizar o `picturefill.` Mas está difícil conciliar os dois plugins. O `picturefill` utiliza `span` dentro de `span` e o Cycle2 parece identificar cada `span` como um slide independente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por padrão, o [seletor jQuery de `slides`](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php) do Cycle2 é `> img` (seleciona apenas imagens diretamente filhas do `.cycle-slideshow`).

Você precisa alterá-lo para corresponder com a sua marcação. O picturefill utiliza `span`s para cada imagem responsiva, então adicione este atributo ao *container* do Cycle2:

```
data-cycle-slides="> span"
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9d3h5/4/) <sup>(sim, utilizei as mesmas imagens duas vezes)</sup>

Desta forma, todos os `span`s diretamente filhos do `.cycle-slideshow` serão utilizados como slides. Aqui está a marcação utilizada para a demo:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
    data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
    data-cycle-speed="200"
    data-cycle-slides="> span"
    >

    <span data-picture data-alt="Uma foto">
        <span data-src="http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/external/imgs/small.jpg"></span>
        <span data-src="http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/external/imgs/medium.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 400px)"></span>
        <span data-src="http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/external/imgs/large.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 800px)"></span>
        <span data-src="http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/external/imgs/extralarge.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)"></span>
    </span>

    <span data-picture data-alt="Uma foto">
        <span data-src="http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/external/imgs/small.jpg"></span>
        <span data-src="http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/external/imgs/medium.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 400px)"></span>
        <span data-src="http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/external/imgs/large.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 800px)"></span>
        <span data-src="http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/external/imgs/extralarge.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)"></span>
    </span>

</div>
```

Obs.: não estou incluindo fallbacks para JS desabilitado nem IE antigo para deixar a demo mais simples. Adicione-os caso necessário.

---

**NOTA:** esta resposta se aplica à versão 1.2.x do Picturefill, visto que esta era sua versão mais recente quando esta resposta foi originalmente escrita.

O Picturefill a partir da versão 2.0 utiliza o elemento `<picture>`, ou também `<img>` com atributos `srcset` e `sizes`. Para que o Cycle funcione com o Picturefill 2.x, você terá então que adaptar o seletor de slides do Cycle para `> picture` ou `> img` dependendo da sintaxe adotada.

Comment: Obrigado @Havenard, meu spellchecker anda falhando. `=]`

Comment: Pelo jeito falhou de novo

Comment: @Havenard poderias sugerir um edit no caso? Não estou vendo typos.

Comment: `ata-media` -> `data-media`

Comment: @Havenard ops, erro de cópia. Obrigado pelo fiddle atualizado também.